# Program is starting every time I search on Unity's search

Tags: search, autostart, tomboy

Every time I hit the windows key (search) and type something the program Tomboy is launched.

This behavior is annoying and I cant find which configuration is causing it.

Also, a new instance is opened for every key a type in the search bar.

Where should I look?

Comment: you mean without hitting Enter?

Comment: yes, just typing any letter

Comment: Can you post the output of `gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case tomboy` (if any)

Comment: com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-default-view ['recipes.scope', 'recipes-recipepuppy.scope', 'news.scope', 'news-googlenews.scope', 'news-yahoostock.scope', 'reference.scope', 'reference-dictionary.scope', 'reference-europeana.scope', 'reference-googlescholar.scope', 'reference-jstor.scope', 'reference-pubmed.scope', 'reference-sciencedirect.scope', '

Comment: ...
notes.scope', 'notes-tomboy.scope', 
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following commands:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-default-view > broken_scope.txt
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-default-view "['applications.scope', 'files.scope']"
```

Now you have an absolute minimal lens scope (only applications and files; no music, no videos, no pictures, ...) (you might have to log off and log on again)

If that corrects your problem and you're happy to continue like this, *leave it alone* as I'm running like this and the dash is very responsive! >:)

If you want to add some of the other stuff back, open `broken_scope.txt` and add them one by one to the second command above, and test whether the problem comes back.  If it has, remove the last one and continue with the others...

Comment: And if it does work, accept my answer and vote it up when you get enough reputation on this site! ;-)
If it doesn't add a comment below this one. (sorry to reply so late, busy with other stuff)